# AngularJS - Syntax Translation to Browserfy using Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am on my frist APP and my JavaScript skills are realy realy horrorble. So dont wonder about this question ;)

I found on https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme the guide to use the theming function of Angular Material. The problem is that i use Browserfy, and my App dont accept this Syntax. It looks in my Ctrl like this:

```
function userProfileCtrl($scope, $state, user) {
    'ngInject';

    $scope.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .dark();
    });

}

export default {
    name: 'userProfileCtrl',
    fn: userProfileCtrl
};
```

With this code i get the error "angular.js:13708TypeError: $mdThemingProvider.theme is not a function"

So what i do wrong? i tryed alot of stuff, but without knowing what i do, i waste probably a lot of time for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `config` on $scope when it should be on the app module.

This is my setup and it works. Give it a try.

```
angular.module("app")
    .config(function($injector)
    {
        if ($injector.has("$mdThemingProvider"))
        {
            var mdThemingProvider = $injector.get("$mdThemingProvider");

            mdThemingProvider.theme("default")
            .primaryPalette("blue", {
                "default": "500",
                "hue-1": "400",
                "hue-2": "200",
                "hue-3": "50"
            })
            .accentPalette("green", {
                "default": "600"
            })
            .warnPalette("red");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get a error:  6:0  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: yes. its the error from the compiler. so i dont see any in the frontend because he stops the compiling.